# Event listener for A tag to close overlay menu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an overlay menu that I need to shut when clicking on the links. I have some event listeners but it doesn't work on the links. The menu event used on the burger icon works, the `menuItems` is for the links that doesn't work. I need it to also work with Pjax link

I have tried target the `a` tags like `menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.__overlay_nav_content_list_item a');` but it does not work.

```js
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  var app = function() {
    var body = undefined;
    var menu = undefined;
    var menuItems = undefined;
    var init = function init() {
      body = document.querySelector('body');
      menu = document.querySelector('.burger_menu_icon');
      menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.__overlay_nav_content_list_item');
      applyListeners();
    };

    var applyListeners = function applyListeners() {
      menu.addEventListener('click', function() {
        return toggleClass(body, '__overlay_nav-active');
      });

      menuItems.addEventListener('click', function() {
        return toggleClass(body, '__overlay_nav-active');
      });
    };

    var toggleClass = function toggleClass(element, stringClass) {
      if (element.classList.contains(stringClass))
        element.classList.remove(stringClass);
      else element.classList.add(stringClass);
    };
    init();
  }();
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've tagged this as Javascript for you as, besides the IIFE containing jQuery, you aren't using it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked event bubbling? If menuItems are descendants of menu, clicking the menu items will trigger `menuItems.addEventListener('click', function() {` and hence toggle the class, then the event will bubble up to menu and trigger `menu.addEventListener('click', function() {`, removing the class you just added. So the end result is that it looks like nothing changed.

If that is the issue, only use the click event on `menu`, or stop the bubbling up of the event of the menuItems by using `event.stopPropagation()`.

Although i would prefer only using the click event of the menu, first try:
Keep in midn that querySelectorAll() returns  a nodeList, so it's an arraylike object containing all the links, not a single link.

```
Array.from( menuItems ).forEach(function( menuItem ) {
  menuItem.addEventListener('click', function( event ) { // add event here so you have access to it!
    event.stopPropagation(); // call stopPropagation() first
    return toggleClass(body, '__overlay_nav-active'); // Once you return, the function stops.
  });
});
```

so we know that this is the problem or not. Do not forget to add `event` as the parameter for the event handler function.

Comment: I have tried but did not work. Where would I put that in the code? I am fairly new to jquery

Comment: You are not using jquery. Apart from importing it, you are not using it for anything. And inside the menuItems click event handler: `menuItems.addEventListener('click', function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); return toggleClass(body, '__overlay_nav-active'); });`

Comment: menuItems.addEventListener('click', function () {
                        return toggleClass(body, '__overlay_nav-active').event.stopPropagation();

                    }); I tried this to no avail

Comment: Once you return, the function stops, so you have to call `event.stopPropagation()` Before returning toggleClass(), since once you return from inside a function, any code written after that return statement it will not run. Do not forget to put event as the parameter of the function either. `function( event ) { ... }`.

Comment: menuItems.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                        return toggleClass(body, '__overlay_nav-active');

                    }); lis this right? it did not work

Comment: ugh, It's querySelectorAll(), it's a nodeList, not a single menuItem. sorry.

Comment: Updated my code. You ahve to loop over all the items. You were attaching the event to like a javascript object instead of to the actual menuItems on the screen. Hope it finally works.

Comment: there is one issue. It seems to ruin my pjax link so reloads the page normall

Comment: is this because of the event.stopPropagation?

Comment: I removed event.stopPropagation and it functions how I need.

Comment: Well, your question did not actually show how the ajax redirection works im your code, so I could not anticipate on that. Glad you got it to work. :)